# How can I install the Wicket framework?

Tags: java, wicket

How can I install the Wicket framework? Please guide me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are step-by-step instructions I put together a few months ago for installing Wicket. They list everything I did to set Wicket up on a vanilla machine with Eclipse installed.

---

- Downloaded JDK 6_22
- Downloaded Maven 3.01
- Installed JDK to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
- Unzipped maven to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.1
- Updated system environment variables:

  - `M2`
    C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.1
  - `M2_HOME`
    %M2_HOME%\bin = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.1\bin
  - `JAVA_HOME`
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
  - `M2_REPO`
    C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository (exact path will vary based on your username/Windows version)

- Followed instructions at [Wicket quickstart](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html), generating this Maven command:

  ```
  mvn archetype:create
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.1
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany
  -DartifactId=projName
  ```
- Ran above Maven command from command line
- Relevant files, including Wicket source, were downloaded automatically, based on POM.
- Ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create an Eclipse project based on above
- Imported project into Eclipse with `File > Import..., Existing Projects`
- Ran `Start.java` in the test folder and found the test app up and running at `http://localhost:8080`

**Optional: support for third-party code, like Wicket Extensions**
Manually adding the Wicket Extensions JAR file to to the `M2_REPO` directory won't work.

Instead, run `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies` after updating the POM. (Wicket Extensions is included but commented out in the default POM.) Then configure the build path in Eclipse by using `Add Variables...` (not `Add JARs`), select `M2_REPO`, press `Extend`, find the desired JAR (in this case, Wicket Extensions).

A similar procedure should work for other third-party libraries.

---

I was originally going to keep updating [this web page](http://compiledpuns.blogspot.com/2010/12/wicket-installation.html) with more instructions, but I've been working on other things lately. <s>Eventually, though, I hope to get around to instructions on how to configure Wicket with Tomcat instead of relying solely on the jetty server it comes with.</s>

### UPDATE

Instructions for deploying to Tomcat are here:

- Download and install [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) and [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org).
- Create the following directory structure:

  ```
  \WicketTomcat
    +---src
    | +---main
    | | +---java
    | | | \---com
    | | |   \---HelloWicket
    | | |         HelloWorld.java
    | | |         HelloWorld.html
    | | |         HelloWorldApplication.java
    | | \---webapp
    | |   \---WEB-INF
    | |         web.xml
    | \---test
    |   \---java
    +---lib
    |     junit.jar
    |     log4j.jar
    |     servlet-api.jar
    |     slf4j-api.jar
    |     slf4j-log4j.jar
    |     wicket.jar
    |     wicket-extensions.jar
    +---target
      build.xml
  ```
- Fill in the files as follows:

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.HelloWicket;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;

public class HelloWorld extends WebPage {
    public HelloWorld() {
        add(new Label("message", "Hello, Wicket!"));
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Wicket Tomcat test title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span wicket:id="message">Message goes here</span>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorldApplication.java**

```
package com.HelloWicket;

import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

public class HelloWorldApplication extends WebApplication {
    public HelloWorldApplication() {
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#getHomePage()
     */
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return HelloWorld.class;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>Extremely simple example of deploying Wicket on Tomcat</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>development</param-value> <!-- Wicket mode (development or deployment) -->
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HelloWicket</filter-name> <!-- To be used in filter-mapping > filter-name below -->
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.HelloWicket.HelloWorldApplication <!-- Fully qualified name of WebApplication class -->
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HelloWicket</filter-name> <!-- Must match filter > filter-name above -->
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!-- Take control of all URLs that start with http://localhost:8080/HelloWicket/  -->
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>

<!--
After deploying to Tomcat, access with http://localhost:8080/HelloWicket/.

Source: http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/helloworld.html
-->
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="war" name="HelloWicket" basedir=".">
    <property name="final.name" value="HelloWicket" />
    <property name="src.main.dir" value="src/main/java" />
    <property name="src.test.dir" value="src/test/java" />
    <property name="src.web.dir" value="src/main/webapp" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="target" />
    <property name="build.main.classes" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="build.test.classes" value="${build.dir}/test-classes" />
    <property name="build.test.reports" value="${build.dir}/test-reports" />
    <property name="build.reports.dir" value="${build.dir}/reports" />
    <property name="tomcat.dir" value="..\..\..\..\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\webapps" />

    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" failonerror="false" />
        <delete file="${final.name}.war" failonerror="false" />
    </target>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.main.classes}" />
        <javac destdir="${build.main.classes}" target="1.6" source="1.6" srcdir="${src.main.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
        <copy todir="${build.main.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${src.main.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*" />
                <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build.test.classes}" />
        <javac destdir="${build.test.classes}" target="1.6" source="1.6" srcdir="${src.test.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="build.classpath" />
                <pathelement path="${build.main.classes}" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${build.test.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${src.test.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*" />
                <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="test" depends="test-compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build.test.reports}" />
        <junit dir="./" failureproperty="test.failure" printSummary="yes" fork="true" haltonerror="true">
            <sysproperty key="basedir" value="." />
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="build.classpath" />
                <pathelement path="${build.main.classes}" />
                <pathelement path="${build.test.classes}" />
            </classpath>
            <batchtest todir="${build.test.reports}">
                <fileset dir="${src.test.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <mkdir dir="${build.reports.dir}" />
        <junitreport todir="${build.reports.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${build.test.reports}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${build.reports.dir}" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>
    <target name="war" depends="test">
        <war destfile="${build.dir}/${final.name}.war" webxml="${src.web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <lib dir="lib">
                <include name="wicket*.jar" />
                <include name="slf4j*.jar" />
                <include name="log4j*.jar" />
                <include name="servlet*.jar" />
            </lib>
            <classes dir="${build.main.classes}" />
            <fileset dir="${src.web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*" />
                <exclude name="**/web.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="war">
        <echo>Deploying .war to local Tomcat</echo>
        <copy todir="${tomcat.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="${final.name}.war" />
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

As I did with the original answer, I posted a slightly more explanatory version of this answer [here](http://compiledpuns.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-set-wicket-up-with-tomcat.html), but this should really be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell how to install in Fedora operating system?

Comment: @Anto, sorry, I'm not familiar with installing Wicket on Fedora. If you have other requirements, please edit them into your question instead of just telling people to "guide you."

Comment: Hi i have tried the above steps, but i'm not getting it right. When i try to execute the mvn command, its showing the command not found.. Still i have updated the environment varibles, but have a doubt these environment varibles have to be created or to be updated in "Path" variable? And i have to download Maven source or binary format?

Comment: Afaik all major linux distributions should have maven in their repositories. Maybe you will get a working installation by trying _yum install maven2_.

Comment: @Anto, again, these are Windows-specific instructions. They will not work for Linux.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have maven2 installed, then go to http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html, copy the command line from there and run it. That should create a project with a demo application and page that you can import in your favourite IDE and play with.

Answer (score 4):

http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

Here is some information for creating a Wicket quickstart project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: No problem, if you haven't already you might want to also take a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use wicket together with other frameworks (Spring, JPA, Hibernate, Guice,...) you can generate sample maven commands at this page: http://www.jweekend.com/dev/LegUp

For every archetype you will get a sample project with simple functionality which can be used as base for your further development.